# aws "Cannot create enum from " + regionName + " value!"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am working on aws. I am getting "Cannot create enum from " + regionName + " value!".  I know we could change to the latest SDK jar file, but I want with out changing the jar file to rectify this issue.  I am facing this issue at `Regions.fromName(String regionName)` method.  Here is my code:

```
    for(com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Region region : describeRegionsResult.getRegions()){
        String regionName = region.getRegionName();
        Regions regionsValue = fromNames(regionName);
        Region regionToDiscover = Region.getRegion(regionsValue);
    }
```

Is there is way to convert `describeRegionsResult.getRegions()` to `com.amazonaws.regions.Regions`.

Answer (score 12):

The latest version of the Java SDK as of this answer (1.11.13) supports the following Regions:

```
Enum                    Name
Regions.GovCloud        us-gov-west-1
Regions.US_EAST_1       us-east-1
Regions.US_WEST_1       us-west-1
Regions.US_WEST_2       us-west-2
Regions.EU_WEST_1       eu-west-1
Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1    eu-central-1
Regions.AP_SOUTH_1      ap-south-1
Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1  ap-southeast-1
Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_2  ap-southeast-2
Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_1  ap-northeast-1
Regions.AP_NORTHEAST_2  ap-northeast-2
Regions.SA_EAST_1       sa-east-1
Regions.CN_NORTH_1      cn-north-1
```

You can see when each region was added into the SDK here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blame/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/regions/Regions.java

If you are trying to use one of those names with `Regions.fromName`, but your version of the SDK doesn't have that yet, it is *impossible* to get an enum for that region.  You must upgrade the SDK or keep the region as a String.

Comment: us-east-2 is missing and crashing for me

Answer (score 7):

dont know if its still relevent but my problem was that i wrote the region as:

US_EAST_1

but the right way to write it is:

us-east-1

Answer (score 3):

I replaced `Region.US_EAST_1` with `us-east-1` and it worked.
I think we can skip the enumeration and directly add the region awsconfiguration.json file

Answer (score 0):

For android add latest dependencies... solved for me...

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.3'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-sns:2.3.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating Maven Project with Force Update Of Snapshots/Releases as checked.

Steps to do so:

1. Right Click on your java project from Project Explorer window.
2. Go To Maven. Go To Update Project. (For Eclipse users you can directly go to update project by pressing key combination of Alt + F5).
3. A window with the title Update aven Project will appear, make sure that your project over there is listed and checked.
4. Click on "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases" checkbox.
5. Click Ok Button.
6. Try To Re-Run your code and see.!